# File Existing in Android

Tags: android

I have the ID of my resource in my raw folder, something like:

```
73837383
```

how can I check if the file exists in the app?

Thanks for any help you can provide...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
booelan exists = false;
try {
getResources().openRawResource(73837383);
exists = true;
} catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
  // not found
}
```

See
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource(int)

Comment: Seems that the Exception is a static inner class of Resources. I have updated the code sample. I hope it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Android generates ids for resources dynamically, you cannot store an id and expect it to always be the same. Instead you should reference ids by their name, like R.id.someId. That value will contain the generated id and will be updated with the most recent id that is generated.